# How would you provide an API endpoint to a user that accepts params? (GrapQL/ApolloServer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am new to GraphQl/ApolloServer (and server-side practices in general) and have been interested in building a small personal project for experience.

The process of the project is as follows:

- A user can add an endpoint to their form action, with their api key appended e.g. `https://myprojectsendpoint.com/[apikey]`
- Server handles submission

The graphql api would be exposed at `https://myprojectsendpoint.com/graphql`. My end goal is to provide the user with a 'prettier' url (eg. `https://myprojectsendpoint.com/[apikey]`) that would effectively be an alias for the original graphql api url.

My question is: is it possible to somehow customize the graphql api url that the user sees?

Would I have to create that endpoint and use that to communicate/pass the api key to graphql server from there?

Any knowledge on the matter would he greatly appreciated! I am happy to elaborate further if needed.

Comment: Never put credentials, such as api keys, in the URL. Unless you mean "Public api identifier"

Comment: What exactly is that "*endpoint [for] their form action*", and what does it have to do with GraphQL? Does it use GraphQL itself? Or do you want to provide a separate `/graphql` api that is used only for registering these form endpoints?

Comment: Form action is in reference to how an end user would use the api on the front-end eg <form action=''https://myprojectsendpoint.com/[apikey]">. I would ultimately like the url to be called in that format. However, my server would be accessible on https://myprojectsendpoint.com/graphql

Comment: So these are really just HTTP endpoints for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST requests? Then no, you can't use Apollo/GraphQL for *that* part of your server.

Comment: Thank you - to clarify my end qoal a little further, I would like to provide the user with a 'prettier' url as opposed to the graphql endpoint with params. Although I am unsure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

as per the graphql/ApolloServer specs it operates on a set of schemas and resolvers, and exposes a single endpoint `/graphql` so to access any information over on the resolvers you need to pass it as a query,

for example, you want every user to pass an argument or parameter when calling the endpoint that would create any information over on the server

in order to do that the query can include arguments that would be available to the server upon recieving the query

let's take a more applicable approach
assume we have this schema below over on the server where we  also have a resolver attached to it

```js
type Query {
  rollDice(numDice: Int!, numSides: Int): [Int]
}
```

Resolver:

```js
var root = {
  rollDice: ({numDice, numSides}) => {
   // any code you want server to execute
  }
};
```

query:

```js
query RollDice($dice: Int!, $sides: Int) {
  rollDice(numDice: $dice, numSides: $sides)
}`
```

TL;DR we can pass arguments in grphql query that is accessible to resolvers
Ref: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/